# How can you create a route to a host using the host name in TwinCAT?

Tags: twincat

Have you ever been able to connect to a host, while you have the "Host Name" selected? I can only ever connect to a host when I select "IP Address".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I discovered that it has to do with firewall settings. In order to connect via hostname you need to have "File and Printer Sharing" enabled in Windows Firewall.

I did some quick testing just now and it appears that you only need to have File Sharing open on the XAE PC, not the target.

**EDIT:**
After further research, I believe that using hostnames for connections makes use of NetBios name resolution in Windows. This requires UDP port 137 to be open (strangely, only for inbound connections on the originating PC). Enabling `File and Printer Sharing` in the firewall opens this port, among others. For more granularity, you can open Advanced Settings in Windows Firewall and enable just `File and Printer Sharing (NB-Name-In)` under Inbound Rules.

[image]

Comment: My local beckhoff support said its bugged and we should always use IP, didnt think about it since, was years ago. I will try this as it is super annoying when using dhcp and the router gets all weird and doesent find targets on network, the problem that would not show when using a network switch or any non beckoff pc 

Comment: Where did you change these options? Under `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings`? There I can only find an option to enable both file and printer sharing simultaneously. Also, wtf this option seems very unrelated x).

Comment: You're not enabling file sharing but rather unblocking the associated ports in the firewall. So it will be under `Control Panel\Windows Defender Firewall`. Select "Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall" and you will see `File and Printer Sharing` in the list. I'll update my answer with more detail.